# Remix-auth not authenticating

Tags: typescript, authentication, remix.run

Recently implemented a simple login functionality with `remix-auth` and `prisma` but... in a weird way, inside my action function, the true credentials go to catch block a throw a `Response` error. Everything is good though. When incorrect credentials are entered, or csrf is faulty (using `remix-utils`), I see the message.
Implementation:

/services/session.server.ts

```js
import { createCookieSessionStorage } from "@remix-run/node";

if (!process.env.SESSION_SECRET) {
  throw new Error("SESSION_SECRET is not set");
}

// export the whole sessionStorage object
export const sessionStorage = createCookieSessionStorage({
  cookie: {
    name: "_vSession",
    sameSite: "lax",
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: true, 
    secrets: [process.env.SESSION_SECRET], 
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", 
  },
});

export const { getSession, commitSession, destroySession } = sessionStorage;
```

/services/auth-strategies/form.strategy.server.ts

```js
import type { UserSession } from "types/auth";
import { FormStrategy } from "remix-auth-form";
import prisma from "lib/prisma";
import { AuthorizationError } from "remix-auth";
import { compare } from "bcrypt";

export const formStrategy = new FormStrategy<UserSession>(async ({ form }) => {
  const username = form.get("username") as string;
  const password = form.get("password") as string;
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { username },
    select: {
      id: true,
      username: true,
      role: true,
      password: true,
    },
  });
  if (!user)
    throw new AuthorizationError("user doesn't exist", {
      name: "userNotFound",
      message: "user doesn't exist",
      cause: "userNotFound",
    });

  const passwordMatch = await compare(password, user.password as string);

  if (!passwordMatch)
    throw new AuthorizationError("invalid username or password", {
      name: "invalidCredentials",
      message: "invalid username or password",
      cause: "invalidCredentials",
    });

  const { password: userPassword, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
  return userWithoutPassword;
});
```

My form strategy name is inside this exported object

/services/auth-strategies/index.ts

```js
export const AuthStrategies = {
  FORM: "form"
} as const;
```

and all being used as usual here:

/services/auth.server.ts

```js
import { Authenticator } from "remix-auth";
import { sessionStorage } from "~/services/session.server";
import { AuthStrategies } from "~/services/auth_strategies";
import { formStrategy } from "./auth_strategies/form.strategy.server";
import { UserSession } from "types/auth";

export type AuthStrategy = (typeof AuthStrategies)[keyof typeof AuthStrategies];

export const authenticator = new Authenticator<UserSession | Error | null>(
  sessionStorage,
  {
    sessionErrorKey: "vSessionError",
    sessionKey: "vSession",
    throwOnError: true,
  }
);

authenticator.use(formStrategy, AuthStrategies.FORM);
```

`root.tsx`:

```js
import { authenticator } from "~/services/auth.server";
import { MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/react";

...

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const headers = new Headers();

  // i18n
  const locale = await i18next.getLocale(request);

  // CSRF
  const [token, cookieHeader] = await csrf.commitToken();

  // Setting headers
  headers.append("Set-Cookie", await i18nCookie.serialize(locale));
  headers.append("Set-Cookie", cookieHeader as string);

  return json({ locale, csrf: token }, { headers });
};

...
```

and in the `_index.tsx` I'm just redirecting to dashboard:

```js
import type { LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/react";
import { authenticator } from "~/services/auth.server";

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  return await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
  });
};
```

Now in my `login` page:

```
...
// Loader
export async function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  return await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
  });
}

// Page
export default function Login() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("login");
  return (
    <Container className="sm:px-20 sm:py-10">
      <Title className="text-center">{t("title")}</Title>
      <Space h="xs" />
      <LoginForm />
    </Container>
  );
}

// Action
export async function action({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) {
  try {
    await csrf.validate(request);
    return await authenticator.authenticate("form", request, {
      successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof CSRFError)
      return json(
        { error: "error with authenticating, please refresh" },
        { status: 403 }
      );
    if (error instanceof AuthorizationError)
      return json({ error: error.message }, { status: 401 });
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      // @!@ FLOWS HERE @!@
      return null;
    }
  }
}

// Error Boundary
export function ErrorBoundary() {
 ...
}
```

The `Form` component -- although not really necessary:

```
...
  return (
    <Form
      method="post"
      onSubmit={loginForm.onSubmit((_values, event) =>
        submit((event as React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>).currentTarget)
      )}
    >
      <AuthenticityTokenInput name="_vCsrf" />
      <TextInput.../>
      <Space h={"sm"} />
      <PasswordInput.../>
      ...
      <Button
        type="submit" ... >
        {t("login")}
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Again, I commented on the part of the login page where the code goes into as `@!@ FLOWS HERE @!@`. Why is such behavior happening? If I don't put the authenticator is try/catch, I get redirected successfully, though on wrong credentials, the `ErrorBoundry` gets rendered!

Comment: The error btw is the redirect object. it's not an error, it's object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All configurations are correct. Since remix-auth throws the Response on successful authentication, it flows to catch block. It's the expected behavior on remix application to throw redirections to stop loaders and actions from further execution. You can Either re-throw or return the resopnse on :

```js
if (error instanceof Response) {
      // @!@ FLOWS HERE @!@
      return error;
    }
```

then you get the successful authentication